# C# database connection class not working

Tags: c#

Im following a C# database connection tutorial however the code they provide for the connection class has a problem, it has an error on dat_set which I'm assuming needs to be set as a variable but I'm unsure. Having looked at the code the tutorial provides many times what i have is exactly the same

The errors are these lines

```
da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
return dat_set;
```

Here is what i have

```
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace JBT
{
    class DBConnect
    {
        private string sqlString;
        private string strCon;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;

        public string Sql
        {
            set { sqlString = value; }
        }

        public string connection_string
        {
            set { strCon = value; }
        }

        public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
        {
            get
            { return MyDataSet(); }
        }

        private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);

            con.Open();

            da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con);
            da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
            con.Close();

            return dat_set;
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you copy this code from? Is it here? http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p6.html (seems an exact copy & paste)

Comment: You show where the error happens, but you do not say what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dataset that you want to Fill need to be intialized before

```
  private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
  {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);

        con.Open();

        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;
    }
```

Of course this could work only if you have initialized the `sqlString` and the `strCon` before calling this code. This should be assumed because you say that the error occurs at the Fill line

Comment: ahhh I completely missed that. Cheers for that

Answer (score 0):

The
    System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet() is not what you have to put in your code if you are using **Mysql**

first initialize the code.
then write methods to open and close connection.
now you are ready for the db connection.

```
    public class DbConnection
    {
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    private void initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "yourdatabase";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString = "server=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";uid=" + uid + ";password=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection

    private bool openConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch(ex.Number)
            {
                    case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                    case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }



    }
```

if you want to develop complete db connection use this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL
helped me a lot :)